# Installed 14.04 on a non-PAE (Pentium-M), but now I can't update ("This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.")

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg

Here is what I'm looking at. This isn't my computer. I repair PC's and I had an end user with this low powered laptop running XP so I decided to let him try out lubuntu. The install went smoothly with the non-PAE boot switch, but now I can't update anything. I'd rather not have to format and start over since he's spent time configuring his system. Any tips would be appreciated. I tried sudo apt-get clean, sudo apt-get install -f, sudo apt-get update. No go.

Also his touchpad stopped working, the wireless stopped working, the keyboard works in firefox but not chrome, and in firefox the address bar sometimes turns black and gray for some reason. I was hoping the update would help address some of this stuff.

Here's the message I get trying to update:

```
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed/main linux-image-3.13.0-26-generic i386 3.13.0-26.48 [14.6 MB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic i386 3.13.0-24.47 [14.6 MB]
Fetched 29.2 MB in 2min 19s (208 kB/s)                                         
(Reading database ... 169286 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-26-generic_3.13.0-26.48_i386.deb ...
This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-26-generic_3.13.0-26.48_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-26-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic_3.13.0-24.47_i386.deb ...
This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic_3.13.0-24.47_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-26-generic_3.13.0-26.48_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic_3.13.0-24.47_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Software update fails with "the package system is broken"

Comment: I just found this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE so I might be able to figure this out on my own

Comment: That help document didn't help :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When installing on a non-pae capable system using `forcepae` option you may still boot without this option set in Grub. Subsequent kernel updates will then fail.

To overcome this add the following line to your `/etc/default/grub` (source: [commment #4 to bug #1307105](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1307105/comments/4)):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash forcepae"
```

Then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot your system for changes to take effect.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. It also fixed my disabled touchpad and wireless.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the i386 version of fake-pae might do the trick and allow upgrades.  I had a similar problem on my Dell Latitude D600.  The only way I found that worked was to put the Dell's hdd in newer machine, install Ubuntu 14.04 on it, return the hdd to the Dell and then install fake-pae i386. Thereafter all worked fine.