# How do I get a version of ubuntu for pentium M?

Tags: upgrade, system-installation

I have an Asus notebook which I am trying to run ubuntu on. It has a Pentium M processor running in it. So when I try to install Ubuntu 13.10 it asks me to install an appropriate kernel for this old Asus M6000 of mine.

It is not provided on the disk, despite being made for older systems.

I want to make it into a file server but I can't because of this error.
I am only a novice at this. It is my 2nd Ubuntu build.

Comment: You might be using the same cd for your new computer and this old laptop, but in fact your new computer could be a 64-bit one and run fine with 64-bit ubuntu, while your Pentium M laptop is 32-bit and needs a 32-bit ubuntu cd.

Comment: for 14.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/464376/can-i-install-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-a-laptop-without-pae for older releases use fake-pae: http://askubuntu.com/questions/117744/how-can-i-install-on-a-non-pae-cpu-error-kernel-requires-features-not-present

Answer (score 0):

You just have to download the 32bit version for a system running a Pentium-M. I have a netbook running Ubuntu, and Mint, just have to use the 32bit version disks.

If the issue is you're unsure how to get the 32bit disk (the Ubuntu site always shows the 64bit in the download box), all you have to so, is when it brings you to the download link, where it says "Choose your flavour", just click on the dropdown menu under it, and you will see the 32bit version right there.

Comment: 32-bit won't help if the Pentium can not provide PAE.

Comment: That's not true, my netbook has an atom cpu, and they don't support pae, and it works fine on my netbook.