# Will Ubuntu run on old Dell Pentium M 512 ram

Tags: laptop, pae

Trying to reuse this old dell laptop,,,I can't find a ubuntu or mint distro that the cpu will accept?
  Is it just too old to function?  Came with xp pro 32 bit?

Thanks for help/suggestions

John in Dallas

Comment: No its not to old, this should run [Lubuntu 14.04 32bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso) and here an install guide -> [Lubuntu/InstallingLubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/InstallingLubuntu)

Comment: See the above link for instructions on booting with the "forcepae" parameter on 14.04. You might like to consider Xubuntu or Lubuntu as they are often more responsive on older systems.

Answer (score 0):

For a laptop of that age I suspect the CPU or mainboard does not support PAE which all current distros seem to require. I would suggest Lubuntu 12.04 which you can download the official iso files from http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/precise/release/ . 12.04 is not the most current Ubuntu release but is it an LTS (Long Term Support) release so it will have support till April 2017.

Comment: Why Lubuntu 12.04 and not Lubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: 14.04 supports Pentium M with the "forcepae" kernel parameter. See [Can I install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a laptop without pae?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/464376/can-i-install-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-a-laptop-without-pae)

Comment: Lubuntu 12.04 is not an LTS release. Lubuntu 14.04 Long Term Support is for a period of three years after the release date (until April, 2017).

Comment: @karel: I stand corrected. Lubuntu is about the only release I know of that 12.04 is not LTS then, so I am sure it's an easy to assume it would be to.

Comment: Trisquel would work. Trisquel has a non-pae kernel in the repos. You may have better luck with a light weight os such as tinycore