# Installed 14.04 on a alix board, can not update

Tags: 14.04, apt, non-pae

It's the same question like here:
[Installed 14.04 on a non-PAE (Pentium-M), but now I can't update ("This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.")](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463440/installed-14-04-on-a-non-pae-pentium-m-but-now-i-cant-update-this-kernel-d)

I get a similar error message:

```
This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-33-generic_3.19.0-33.38~14.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-33-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-33-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-33-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-33-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.19.0-30-generic_3.19.0-30.34~14.04.1_i386.deb ...
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-30-generic_3.19.0-30.34~14.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-30-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-33-generic_3.19.0-33.38~14.04.1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-30-generic_3.19.0-30.34~14.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

But the solution does not help. I have already the forcepae entry in the grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash forcepae"
```

What else can I do. I'd like to install a DHCP Server. But like this it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check the partitions on your system by performing a `sudo df -h`

See if one or more of the partitions is full, as in:

```
 /dev/vda1 236M 230M 0 100% /boot
```

Comment: Only 73% is used.